# Comparing and filtering data based on timestamp using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sorting, timestamp

I have two cell arrays, `tb_ref` and `tb_test`, with contents as follow:

```
tb_ref = {'2009-04-13 10:50:00.000' 6.0708560 339.81910; ...
          '2009-04-13 11:00:00.000' 6.1039610 333.53540; ...
          '2009-04-13 11:10:00.000' 5.2654460 217.59230; ...
          '2009-04-13 12:00:00.000' 6.4318040 362.63540; ...
          '2009-04-13 12:10:00.000' 7.1082010 565.98960; ...
          '2009-04-13 12:20:00.000' 6.2918340 440.54640; ...
          '2009-04-13 12:50:00.000' 8.0200310 757.24960};

tb_test = {'13-Apr-2009 10:50:00' 3.1; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 11:00:00' 33; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 11:10:00' 21; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 11:20:00' 160; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 11:30:00' 143; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 11:40:00' 74; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 11:50:00' 39; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 12:00:00' 36; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 12:10:00' 56; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 12:20:00' 44; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 12:30:00' 20; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 12:40:00' 34; ...
           '13-Apr-2009 12:50:00' 75};
```

I want to select the data from both arrays wherever the time stamp matches in both and store it in a new cell array. For example `2009-04-13 10:50:00.000` matches in both arrays hence the new array must have the following values:

```
'2009-04-13 10:50:00.000'     6.0708560    339.81910    3.1
```

And so on. How I can do this?

Comment: Is this an actual `table` or is this a cell array?  The syntax of your table specification is invalid.  Please edit your post to clarify this point.

Comment: Actually its cell array. I modified it. Please have a look

Comment: It have two different table recorded in as mention  timestamp. However my main point is to filter the data as mention in question

Comment: Why your table or cell array has randomly placed `'` and `"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure the date format matches across sets, it's probably best to format the dates in *both* sets first using [`datestr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html):

```
tb_ref(:, 1) = cellstr(datestr(tb_ref(:, 1), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF'));
tb_test(:, 1) = cellstr(datestr(tb_test(:, 1), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF'));
```

Now, assuming each time stamp can occur only once in each set, you can find the common entries using [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) and combine them into a new cell array:

```
[dates, indexRef, indexTest] = intersect(tb_ref(:, 1), tb_test(:, 1));
tb_new = [dates tb_ref(indexRef, 2:3) tb_test(indexTest, 2)];
```

And here's the result you should get for your example above:

```
tb_new =

  7×4 cell array

    '2009-04-13 10:50:00.000'    [6.0709]    [339.8191]    [3.1000]
    '2009-04-13 11:00:00.000'    [6.1040]    [333.5354]    [    33]
    '2009-04-13 11:10:00.000'    [5.2654]    [217.5923]    [    21]
    '2009-04-13 12:00:00.000'    [6.4318]    [362.6354]    [    36]
    '2009-04-13 12:10:00.000'    [7.1082]    [565.9896]    [    56]
    '2009-04-13 12:20:00.000'    [6.2918]    [440.5464]    [    44]
    '2009-04-13 12:50:00.000'    [8.0200]    [757.2496]    [    75]
```

Comment: It is not working. It saying they must have same variable. The two tables contains different parameters values except timestamp

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath: Check this newest version. I fixed an error.

Comment: Thanks. it works great of having same timestamp specification. But in my case I have two table whose timestamp represented by different way. Since this is just a sample of data I gave you. So not applicable for me to use this. I modified the question. Please have a look and tell me wheather u can help me on this ?

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath: I've updated the answer to handle different date formats.